# CMAKE package config and flag setup

Tags: opencv, cmake, blob, compiler-flags, ros

I'm quit a noob at this area, but I need to include in my cmake file (for a ROS node):

```
gcc main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o test `pkg-config cvblob opencv --libs`
```

I want to use the cvblob and opencv lib in a ROS node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from [ROS wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples#Using_pkg-config_to_find_an_external_dependency), the opencv dependencies are declared in the manifest.xml

```
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/FindPkgConfig.cmake)
pkg_check_modules(CVBLOB REQUIRED cvblob)
include_directories(${CVBLOB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${CVBLOB_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(bagDetect ${CVBLOB_LIBRARIES})
```